# comparing two dates after converting from unix format in mysql

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I have a date that I am sending from controller to query in this format

start date `02/13/2019` end date `03/13/2019`

First it was normal timestamp which I used and these query condition seemed to work

```
DATE_FORMAT(o.Timestamp, '%m/%d/%Y') >= '02/13/2019'")
DATE_FORMAT(o.Timestamp, '%m/%d/%Y') <= '03/13/2019'")
```

Now I store timestamp in unix format which is `1550077130`

After that my query conditions become and don't work.

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(o.Timestamp, '%m/%d/%Y') >= '02/13/2019'")
FROM_UNIXTIME(o.Timestamp, '%m/%d/%Y') <= '03/13/2019'")
```

Comment: you have error  ?? show error message .. wrong result ?? ..show your code  .. a data sample and the exptected  result

Answer (score 0):

try converting string to date and compare date

```
    select from my_table o
    where    FROM_UNIXTIME(o.Timestamp) >= str_to_date('02/13/2019', '%d/%m%Y')
    AND   FROM_UNIXTIME(o.Timestamp) <= str_to_date('03/13/2019', '%d/%m%Y')
```